# Scrolling in divs with position fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to bild something like this: https://interfacelovers.com/

That a content is fixed on the right, and only the left side scrolls, to a specific height and then scrolls normaly all the page, the problem is that in my case when i scroll down on the right div, my content moves. Is there a way of doing this trough javascript (I believe it's how they are doing it).

Cheers

Comment: Its called parallax scrolling, there are lots of plugins that will help you create such effects :)

Comment: http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/ this will help you

Answer (score 1):

### The Sticky Position

You can achieve this using CSS3, check out the below snippet.

Please take care of the following:

1. Always check browser compatibility - I have not done this for you and it is your responsibility.
2. You might need some extra CSS to make it nice and responsive.

Good Luck!

```css
#bigContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#theSticky {
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0px;
}

.rightItems {
  margin-left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='bigContainer'>
  <div id='theSticky'>
  </div>
  <div class='rightItems'>
  </div>
  <div class='rightItems'>
  </div>
  <div class='rightItems'>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='rightItems'>
</div>
<div class='rightItems'>
</div>
<div class='rightItems'>
</div>
<div class='rightItems'>
</div>
<div class='rightItems'>
</div>
<div class='rightItems'>
</div>
<div class='rightItems'>
</div>
<div class='rightItems'>
</div>
<div class='rightItems'>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To fix an element in the page, you can set css property [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to fixed:

```css
#divFixed{
  position:fixed;
  background-color:red;
  top:100px;
  left:200px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

#divBackground{
  background-color:yellow;
  width:100%;
  height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="divFixed">
FIXED
</div>
<div id="divBackground">
NOT FIXED<br>
1<br>
2<br>
3<br>
4<br>
5<br>
6<br>
7<br>
8<br>
9<br>
10<br>
11<br>
12<br>
13<br>
14<br>
15<br>
16<br>
17<br>
18<br>
19<br>
20<br>
</div>
```

You can set the position using properties top,left,right and bottom according to distance from a side of the page.

The linked page https://interfacelovers.com/ use this css property currently whit javascript to change the property when the scroll of the page is down